# How to pass Collection of records from screen flow to aura component and pass aura component to screen flow

Tags: apex, lightning, aura, screen-flow

Here I have requirement to create Flow which calls a aura components here i need to pass Collection of records from screen flow to aura component and pass aura component to screen flow
But while creating design atribute type collection in Aura components i am facing problem
[image]

is there any who can help me in this case? please